# Why is my Modal lagging when opened for the first time

Tags: javascript, css

The lagging seems to appear only the first time it's opened

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/Nairobi02/pen/YzaodxK)

Some reasons why I think this may be happening (but I've been told it's not the case):

**Using one event listener on body and one event handler with multiple conditional statements**

I've done this because i wont the modal to close even if the user clicks outside the modal object

```
open.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    change();

    document.body.addEventListener('click', takeInput);
});

function takeInput(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let form = document.querySelector('.details_section');
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    if (e.target.closest('.shut') || (!e.target.closest('.modal'))) {
        form.reset();
        change();

    }

    else if (e.target.closest('.signin')) {
        if (form.checkValidity()) {
            console.log('true')
            change();
          form.reset();
        }
        else {
            console.log('false')
            form.reportValidity();

        }
    }
    else if (e.target.closest('.reset')) {
        form.reset();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share code for the modal?

Comment: Have you tried it on different computer with more RAM and _not_ on Chrome browser?

Comment: @DragonInTraining Hey, thanks for the reply, Ive shared the codepen link of the modal since i thought posting the entire code would be too much.

[link](https://codepen.io/Nairobi02/pen/YzaodxK)

Comment: @Justinas I checked mozilla's dev browser, chrome and ms edge, the problem seems to be occurring on all of them

Comment: No lagging for me when I try the modal!

Comment: @Justinas i have tested the modal and it's lagging too, i dont think it's related to machine performance, but maybe this modal needs hardware acceleration enabled on browser to get smooth animation?

Comment: Absolutely no difference in any browser between first and subsequent animations - what sort of lag are you talking about though? 100's of milliseconds? 10's?

Comment: I can see bad code though, every time you click `open`, you add another event listener to the body - but if anything that cause the reverse effect - although, on the codepen you seem to remove that event listener on the body, so ... ignore this comment